# Concatenacion de valores en método toString

Tags: java

Tengo una lista con x valores, entonces quiero que si hay más de un valor lo muestre normal, si hay dos valores ponga: "negro **Y** rojo" y si hay más de dos coloque una coma, es decir: "negro**,** rojo **Y** azul". Tengo este código:

```
public String toString() {

    String cadena = nombreLst + " es un Avenger, tiene " + edad + " años.";

    // Bucle para tipTiendaLST

    if (colorTrajeLst != null && colorTrajeLst.size() > 0) {

        cadena += " El color de su traje es ";

        for (Integer index = 0; index < colorTrajeLst.size(); index++) {

            ColorTraje colorTraje = colorTrajeLst.get(index);

            if (colorTrajeLst.size() <= 2) {

                cadena += " y ";

            }

            else {

                cadena += ", ";

            }


            cadena += colorTraje;

        }
```

Seguro que es el cambio más tonto del mundo, pero es que no consigo verlo... muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer sería ir añadiendo los colores y si no estás en la penúltima posición, añadir una coma. En el momento en el que llegas a la penúltima posición en lugar de una coma, colocarías un "y". Por cierto, se te estaba olvidando retornar el valor final.

```
public String toString() {

    String cadena = nombreLst + " es un Avenger, tiene " + edad + " años.";

    // Bucle para tipTiendaLST

    if (colorTrajeLst != null && colorTrajeLst.size() > 0) {

        cadena += " El color de su traje es ";

        for (int index = 0; index < colorTrajeLst.size(); index++) {

            ColorTraje colorTraje = colorTrajeLst.get(index);

            cadena += colorTraje;

            if (index < colorTrajeLst.size()-2) {

                cadena += " , ";

            }

            else if (index < colorTrajeLst.size()-1) {

                cadena += " y ";

            }

        }

    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: ¡Aaaaaahora! Efectivamente así era, el caso es que lo hice pero no fui capaz de volverlo a sacar... mil gracias!

Comment: Nada!! Si te ha sido útil considera votar positivamente mi respuesta. Un saludo!!